# kubernetes nginx.ingress multiple websocket services

Tags: kubernetes, websocket, nginx-ingress

How I can specify more that one service for the nginx ingress websocket annotation?

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/websocket-services: "service-name"
```

the name implies more that one service can be supplied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NGINX Ingress WebSocket support](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/v1.9.1/examples/websocket) page says:

> To load balance a WebSocket application with NGINX Ingress
> controllers, you need to add the **nginx.org/websocket-services**(you use **nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io**)
> annotation to your Ingress resource definition. The annotation
> specifies which services are websocket services. The annotation syntax
> is as follows:

```
nginx.org/websocket-services: "service1[,service2,...]"
```

So `nginx.org/websocket-services: "service-name,service-name1,..,service-nameN"`